# Express rate limiter - Error leyendo Promesas en NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, promesas

estoy intentando leer a traves de una Promise un valor y pasarlo como parametro a Express-rate-limiter
Pero cuando le paso ese valor al constructor del objeto por algun motivo en el response x-ratelimit-reset' aparece como NaN

```
'x-ratelimit-limit': [ 'X-RateLimit-Limit', 2 ],
 'x-ratelimit-remaining': [ 'X-RateLimit-Remaining', 1 ],
 date: [ 'Date', 'Fri, 17 Apr 2020 20:14:07 GMT' ],
 'x-ratelimit-reset': [ 'X-RateLimit-Reset', NaN ] } }
```

Minutes y count estan en un setTimeOut por que despues los traere desde la DB.

```
  let info = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(function(){
        let obj =  { 'minutes': 2, 'count' : 2}
        resolve(obj);
   }, 50);
});
```

Luego creo el objeto Rate Limiter y le paso los minutos que obtengo desde la Promesa.

```
const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: info.then((data)=> {return parseInt(data.minutes,10) }) * 60 * 1000,
  max: info.then((data)=>{ return parseInt(data.count,10) }),
  statusCode: 200,
  message: {
    status: 429,
    error: 'Too many requests, Please try again in 10 minutes.'
  },
  keyGenerator: async function (req, res) {
         return req.ip    

  }


});

// aplico el middleware
app.use("/api/", apiLimiter);
```

Si en vez de poner los minutos que obtengo de Promesa , pongo solo un numero entero por ejemplo 2, funciona bien.

```
const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 2* 60 * 1000,
  max: info.then((data)=>{ return parseInt(data.count,10) }),
  statusCode: 200,

  ....
```

el objeto rate limit del response se ve asi:

```
      'x-ratelimit-limit': [ 'X-RateLimit-Limit', 2 ],
     'x-ratelimit-remaining': [ 'X-RateLimit-Remaining', 1 ],
     date: [ 'Date', 'Fri, 17 Apr 2020 20:27:03 GMT' ],
     'x-ratelimit-reset': [ 'X-RateLimit-Reset', 1587155343 ] }
```

Es probable que el objeto RateLimiter se este creando antes que obtenga la variable minutes de la Promesa. Alguna sugerencia ???? Graciass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que usar `then` no significa que tu promesa se va resolver inmediatamente, usar then, significa que cuando la promesa haya sido resuelta, el valor será devuelto.

Entonces aquí:

```
windowMs: info.then((data)=> {return parseInt(data.minutes,10) }) * 60 * 1000
```

El error consiste inicialmente en que esa promise no se resuelve exactamente al instante, por lo tanto el valor inicial de multiplicar una función entera por unos numeros es:

chan chan chan:

```
NaN
```

Para el caso de max:

```
max: info.then((data)=>{ return parseInt(data.count,10) })
```

De todas maneras no es conveniente que lo tengas así, debido a que puede que funcione debido a que tienes un tiempo corto asignado, en funciones que demoren mas tiempo el resultado de max será siempre una función hasta que no se haya resuelto, por este motivo no es buena idea tener esto:

```
max: info.then((data)=>{ return parseInt(data.count,10) })
```

Para solucionar esto te propongo lo siguiente:

Encerrar este objeto en una función para que puedas usar async - await:

```
async function obtenerDatos(siQuieresPasaleParametros){

   let objeto = {
      windowMs: parseInt((await info).minutes, 10) * 60 * 1000,
      max: parseInt((await info).count, 10),
      statusCode: 200,
      message: {
        status: 429,
        error: 'Too many requests, Please try again in 10 minutes.'
      },
      keyGenerator: async function (req, res) {
             return req.ip    

      }


    }

   return objeto;

}

const promesaObjeto = obtenerDatos();
```

Por ultimo no se si sea buena idea esto:

```
app.use("/api/", apiLimiter);
```

Ya que debido a que los datos son asincronos la mayor parte de las vecez va a fallar estrepitosamente, hay una solución y es esta:

```
promesaObjeto.then(res =>{

   app.use("/api/", apiLimiter);

});
```

pero tampoco me acaba de convencer mucho ya que retrasaría la ejecución de `app.use` dependiendo de lo que se demore la promise en resolverse (asumiendo que se resuelva). de lo contrario simplemente nunca se llegaría a `app.use`, entonces aquí un ejemplo resolviendo tu problema:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

    let info = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        setTimeout(function(){
            let obj =  { 'minutes': 2, 'count' : 2}
            resolve(obj);
       }, 50);
    });

    async function obtenerDatos(siQuieresPasaleParametros){

        let objeto = {
           windowMs: parseInt((await info).minutes, 10) * 60 * 1000,
           max: parseInt((await info).count, 10),
           statusCode: 200,
           message: {
             status: 429,
             error: 'Too many requests, Please try again in 10 minutes.'
           },
           keyGenerator: async function (req, res) {
                  return req.ip    
     
           }
     
     
         }
     
        return objeto;
     
     }
     
    const promesaObjeto = obtenerDatos();

    promesaObjeto.then(res =>{
        console.log(res);
        //Aquí tendrías que poner app.use etc...
    });

}
```

donde la palabra reservada `await` hace parte de las funciones asincronas y por lo tanto **solo se puede usar dentro de funciones asincronas** y lo que hace es pausar la ejecución del código hasta que la promesa sea resuelta o ocurra un error. la palabra reservada `await` no se puede usar en el scope global.

conclusión:

Evita usar promises o cualquier cosa que sea asíncrona si debes usarla inmediatamente en el scope global, bueno, esto a menos de que desees que la pagina se vea afectada por carga lenta o se retrase... las promises son buenas para usar dentro de funciones hablo de `.then` y `.catch` y no la propia `promise` en sí, para usarlas en el scope global tambien esta bien, pero entonces deberás tener bien en cuenta en que las vas a usar en el scope global.

Comment: Gracias @Riven , lo que veo es que ahora la funcion del RateLimit , no agrega por ej,  'x-ratelimit-limit': [ 'X-RateLimit-Limit', 2 ] al objeto response y tampoco logro imprimir por ejemplo req.ip en la funcion "keyGenerator".  Puede ser que  promesaObjeto.then(res => {  app.use("/api/", res)   }); no se este cumpliendo o no 
 se este aplicando correctamente como function middleware?

Comment: Ummmm la verdad no sabria decirte, tendrías que editar la pregunta y poner que hace la función del RateLimit como tu dices, ya que pues ahora mismo no esta incluida en la pregunta... pero bueno eso lo mas probable es que sea por que el código es asincrono y tu función del RateLimit sea sincrona y se este ejecutando antes, es una de las posibilidades...

Comment: Claro, es como que cuando encierro el app.use dentro del then ya este no se aplica, pero en cuanto a tu respuesta es correcta, gracias!!